# $(...).DataTable is not a function in angular 8

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am trying to bind datatables in angular8. But **search, sort and pagination are not binding to the datatable** and i am getting an error like $(...).DataTable is not a function. I also deleted node_modules and reinstall. but still getting same error.

component.ts

```
dtOptions:DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    userDetails:any[]= []
  constructor(private registrationservice:RegistrationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 1
    }
    this.registrationservice.getUsers().subscribe(res=>{
        console.log("getdata success");
        console.log(res['data']);
        this.userDetails = res['data'];
        this.dtTrigger.next();       
    })
```

template file

```
<div class="container">
     <div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mt-5">
                <h1 class="text-primary">Users List</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/createuser">Create User</button>
        </div>
        <table  datatable \[dtOptions\]="dtOptions" \[dtTrigger\]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm mt-5">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of userDetails; index as i">
                    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of angular-datatables is this?

Comment: Also check https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1380

Comment: I am working on angular 8

Comment: I meant the angular-datatables library version